# Weird anti-aliasing in custom view

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawing, antialiasing, drawrect

I have a custom `UIView` which is drawn using its `-[drawRect:]` method.

The problem is that the anti-aliasing acts very weird as black lines horizontal or vertical lines are drawn very blurry.

If I disable anti-aliasing with `CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing`, everything is drawn as expected.

Anti-Aliasing:
[alt text http://dustlab.com/stuff/antialias.png](http://dustlab.com/stuff/antialias.png)

No Anti-Aliasing (which looks like the expected result with AA):
[alt text http://dustlab.com/stuff/no_antialias.png](http://dustlab.com/stuff/no_antialias.png)

The line width is exactly 1, and all coordinates are integral values.

The same happens if I draw a rectangle using `CGContextStrokeRect`, but not if I draw exactly the same `CGRect` with `UIRectStroke`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since a stroke expands equal amounts to both sides, a line of one pixel width **must not** be placed on an integer coordinate, but at 0.5 pixels offset.

Calculate correct coordinates for stroked lines like this:

```
CGPoint pos = CGPointMake(floorf(pos.x) + 0.5f, floorf(pos.y) + 0.5f);
```

BTW: Don't cast your values to int and back to float to get rid of the decimal part. There's a function for this in C called `floor`.

Comment: In addition to this, Apple provides some nice tips and sample code in the "Doing Pixel-Exact Drawing" section of the Cocoa Drawing Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCICIJAJ

Comment: here is simple way to avoid without any code at all http://www.techpaa.com/2012/06/avoiding-view-edge-antialiasing.html

Comment: @jeeva `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` is for edges of layers only. The question is about lines drawn in Quartz. Quartz drawing is not affected by `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing`.

Comment: @Nikolai ya you are right UIViewEdgeAntialiasing has no effect on quartz drawing.

Answer (score 0):

in your view frames, you probably have float values that are not integers.  While the frames are precise enough to do fractions of a pixel (float), you will get blurriness unless you cast to an int

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake((int)self.frame.bounds..., (int)...., (int)...., (int)....);
```